# Finding number of n digit Terminate NUMBERS

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, combinatorial-number-theory

> One is allowed to use the digits *5,6,7,8* any number of times to form a terminate number. A *n digit terminate number* is one which contains digit 5 either an even number of times or does not contain digit 5 at all.

**eg** 556,55,876565 , 8 ,6 are all legitimate numbers

My attempt.

Considering an n digit number .

5 can occur 0,2,4,6... t times

Calculating this t **with respect to n** seems to be a problem.
Moreover,if we know t, number of possibilities would be many

**For instance** 5 occurring 2 times could be generalised as

> $nC2\times3^{n-2}$

However arranging the digits of the above number would itself more ways .

I was hoping to know another way to think of this problem and generalise it for a  *n digit terminate number.*

**answer given is**

> $2^{n-1}(2^n + 1)$

Answer (score 3):

In the sequel we only look at numbers that have their digits in $\{5,6,7,8\}$

Let $t_n$ denote the number of terminate numbers of $n$ digits.

Let $s_n$ denote the number of non-terminate numbers $n$ digits.

Starting with a conventional $t_0=1$ and $s_0=0$ we can find these numbers  recursively by means of the following equations:

$$\begin{aligned}t_{n+1}=3t_{n}+s_{n}\\
s_{n+1}=t_{n}+3s_{n}
\end{aligned}
$$
The $t_n$ terminate numbers of $n$ digits all provide $3$ terminate number of $n+1$ digits by adding digit $6,7$ or $8$. The $s_n$ non-terminate numbers of $n$ digits provide $1$ terminate number by adding digit $5$. This declares the first equality, and the second can be explained likewise.

Based on these equalities by induction it can be shown that:$$\begin{aligned}t_{n}=2^{n-1}\left(1+2^{n}\right)\\
s_{n}=2^{n-1}\left(2^{n}-1\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

---

I found the equalities myself but could not make anything of them. What helped was some searching on OEIS. [Here](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C10%2C36%2C136&sort=&language=english&go=Search) and [here](https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C1%2C6%2C28%2C120%2C496&sort=&language=english&go=Search).

Comment: Also note that $t_n+s_n =4^n$, so for example $t_{n+1} = 2t_n+4^n$